# SubscriptionClient doesn't contain CreateFromConnectionString method

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-topics

Am trying to read messages from azure service bus topics and display it using a console app in c#.I found so many online solutions where they were using

```
SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_serviceBusConn, _serviceBustopic, "<subscription name>");
```

when am trying to use the same thing in my program am getting red squiggly line stating **subscriptionclient doesn't contain definition for CreateFromConnection string**.I'm using **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus** package.I found it was there in **Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging**  but I wasn't able to find this in nuget.org.

Comment: Release notes say you need Net 4.6 and to install Windows.Azure.ServiceBus.  See : https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuget here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus

Links to documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus/

Which links to SubscriptionClient docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.subscriptionclient?view=azure-dotnet) (.NET Standard) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient?view=azure-dotnet) (.NET Framework)

But only the SubscriptionClient in the .NET Framework has a CreateFromConnectionString so if you want to use that method you'll have to ensure you're using the .NET Framework version of the package.. Or switch tutorials :)

Additional thought - the tutorials you're following be based on a machine that has .NET framework and a full (non nuget) install of the Azure SDK, rather than the nuget packages, so it may not be clear what difference they have vs you..

I have a project where I use the Microsoft.ServiceBus namespace and my package.config looks like this:

```
<package id="WindowsAzure.ServiceBus" version="3.4.4" targetFramework="net452" />
```

It's an older version of the package, but it definitely has the Microsoft.ServiceBus.SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(). If your packages.config mentions a targetFramework that isn't a full .net framework, you might not have the version of the package that has this method